# Python error: ImportError: DLL Load failed with psycopg2 on Python 3.7

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm getting the following error:

```
 from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have psycopg2 installed, any ideas?

Comment: How did you install Psycopg2? Have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to import here, does `import psycopg2` work?

Comment: installed it using pip install via anaconda prompt - how should I reinstall?

Comment: @hsturgess94 is the problem solved?

Comment: yes I had to install psycopg2-binary

Comment: @hsturgess94 If this answer helped in your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You can try to uninstall the `psycopg2` package by

```
pip uninstall psycopg2
```

and manually try to install any package from [Anaconda-Cloud](https://anaconda.org/search?q=psycopg2&sort=ndownloads&sort_order=-1&reverse=true)  and see whichever works.